# pass two parameter to event handler

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

hello everyone i struggling to pass two parameter to an event handler basically when the page is load it dynamically create some control lable, textfield, and linkbutton when i click on the link button it fire an event handler, here is my problem i want to pass first the Product ID and quantity, the product id is fetch from the database passit thorugh an object where as the quantity it enter by the user

first part of the code it connect to database loop through and display all record on the page dynamcally

---

```
Function test()

    Dim objTemlDall As New Dallyarer
    arr = objTemlDall.getRecord()

    Dim lblname As Label
    Dim lblDes As Label
    Dim lblPrice As Label
    Dim linkItem As LinkButton


    Dim objTemProduct As Product
    For Each objTemProduct In arr

        lblname = New Label
        lblDes = New Label
        lblPrice = New Label
        linkItem = New LinkButton
        txtQuantity = New TextBox




        PrdName.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<br />"))
        lblname.Text = objTemProduct.Name
        PrdName.Controls.Add(lblname)
        PrdName.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<br />"))

        PrdDesc.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<br />"))
        lblDes.Text = objTemProduct.ShortDescription
        PrdDesc.Controls.Add(lblDes)
        PrdDesc.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<br />"))

        PrdPrice.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<br />"))
        lblPrice.Text = objTemProduct.UnitPrice
        PrdPrice.Controls.Add(lblPrice)
        PrdPrice.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<br />"))

        PrdQuantity.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<br />"))
        txtQuantity.ID = "qty"
        PrdQuantity.Controls.Add(txtQuantity)

        PrdQuantity.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<br />"))



        linkItem.Text = "Add to Cart"
        linkItem.ID = objTemProduct.ProductID
        linkItem.CommandArgument = objTemProduct.ProductID
        PrdAddToCart.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<br />"))
        PrdAddToCart.Controls.Add(linkItem)
        PrdAddToCart.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<br />"))

        AddHandler linkItem.Click, AddressOf GetSelectedProduct

    Next objTemProduct

End Function
```

second part when it fire event handler i want to pass txtQuantity data to GetSelectedProduct event handler how can i achieve that please

```
Function GetSelectedProduct(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    SelectedProduct = New Product
    Dim lbLink As LinkButton = CType(sender, LinkButton)
    SelectedProduct.ProductID = lbLink.CommandArgument



    Dim objTemlCart As New Dallyarer
    arr = objTemlCart.getRecord()

    Dim objT As Product

    For Each objT In arr
        If objT.ProductID = SelectedProduct.ProductID Then
            SelectedProduct.ProductID = objT.ProductID
            SelectedProduct.Name = objT.Name
            SelectedProduct.UnitPrice = objT.UnitPrice
        End If
    Next objT


    If Page.IsValid Then
        Dim CartItem As New CartItem
        CartItem.Product = SelectedProduct
        'CartItem.Quantity = CType(Me.txtQuantity.Text, Integer)
        Me.AddToCart(CartItem)
    End If


End Function
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
object.addEventListener(FlexEvent.MouseEvent, function
   (e:MouseEvent) : void {
doSomething(param1, param2);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Send an Object that has those to parameters as it's properties.